# Automapper Update Dictionary Values

Tags: c#

I have an Entity that contains a dictionary, and what i want to achieve is that automapper not simply Replace the dictionary but updates it's values.

```
class ExampleClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string[]> Dictionary { get; set; } 
}

Mapper.CreateMap<ExampleClass, ExampleClass>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));

var originalClass = new ExampleClass();
originalClass.Name = "Original Class";
originalClass.Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string[]>
{
    {0, new []{"V1", "V2", "V3"}},
    {1, new []{"V1", "V2", "V3"}},
    {2, new []{"V1", "V2", "V3"}}
};

var newelyCreatedClass = new ExampleClass();
newelyCreatedClass.Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string[]>
{
    {1, new []{"E1", "E2", "E9"}},
};

Mapper.Map(newelyCreatedClass, originalClass);
```

In the above code, automapper strangely doesn't update the Dictionary element with key == `1` but replaces the whole original one with the one created in `newelyCreatedClass` .

Comment: Well any kind of help ?

Comment: I could use some here please.

Comment: I need an immediate help please, i am stuck with that., i want auto mapper to join the 2 arrays instead of replacing them, and if value exists just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper just automatically compares and sets values if they exist, this is why the property is getting overwritten. But what you can do is use an automapper feature called [Custom Value Resolvers](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers).

Then you could just write a resolver to check the dictionary and its values.

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<ExampleClass, ExampleClass, Dictionary<int, string[]>>
{
    public Dictionary<int, string[]> Resolve(ExampleClass source, ExampleClass destination, Dictionary<int, string[]> member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // logic to iterate through the dictionarys and resolve into dictionary containing values that you want.
    }
}
```