# Emitmapper Don't Map Null

Tags: c#, emitmapper

Due to huge performance difference between `Emitmapper` and `Automapper` as well as an unanswered problem that i am facing with `Automapper`, i decided to move to `Emitmapper`. However i don't know what is the function in `Emitmapper` that is equal to this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Unit, Unit>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));
```

As i can't prevent `Emitmapper` from mapping the null values.

[HINT]: If someone could help me with my problem with automapper [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767558/automapper-update-dictionary-values) i would very thankful.

Comment: Please anyone help guys!

Comment: I ♥ being neglected...